# Как написать свой первый тест java?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста (для прям совсем новичка)
Как написать и запустить свой тест ?
Например есть репозиторий
https://github.com/rojoangel/codewars/tree/master/java/are-they-the-same
там есть класс с реализацией функции и есть класс с тестами.
А как его запустить ? Как вообще эти тесты выполнять ? Что нужно нажать ? Где создать файлы ?
Или нужно вручную дописать класс где будет метод main() и оттуда запустить функцию и тесты сами выполнятся ?

Comment: Гугл, ютуб, что угодно -> java test. Там все подробно и с картинками.

Comment: Кто удалил мой предыдущий комент?)

Comment: @ArturVartanyan это был точно не я, но ваш совет мне действительно помог. В intellij это делать та еще балалайка, как оказалось. Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста! Удачи.